# Flex: passing in function and checking parameters

Tags: apache-flex, function, flex4, callback, closures

I am passing in a function to another function which works well. Let's say function "inner" is being passed to function "outer". My problem is that I want function "outer" to be able to check if there are any parameters in function "inner" and their type. I am using the inner function as a callback so it is important that it has one parameter of a specific type. I would like to catch any problems as early as possible so want the "outer" function to check this.

How can I check a function's parameters? Is this possible in Flex?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be at compile time or is runtime checking OK?

Comment: Compile time ideally but I dont think this would be possible. Runtime is fine I think. I just want to catch any problems as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**at compile time**

Actually it's possible to have compile time checking. It just depends how big a leap you're willing to make. For this to work you will have to write your code in [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) instead of ActionScript and have it [targeting the Flash platform](http://haxe.org/doc/targets/flash) when compiling. There's a good read on Haxe [function types on Devboy's blog](http://www.devboy.org/2011/11/22/understanding-function-types-in-haxe/).

**at runtime**

If you don't want to go that far, here's how to do it in AS: you'll have to use the [describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) function. Suppose you have a test class like this one:

```
public class TestClass {    
    public function test(s:String):void {}
}
```

We can now get information about its functions by writing:

```
var info:XML = describeType(TestClass);
```

Somewhere in this XML object there will be a node that looks like this:

```
<method name="test" declaredBy="net.riastar.test::TestClass" returnType="void">
  <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="false"/>
</method>
```

There it is! All the information you need to do your checking. **But** there's one big caveat in this approach: the `describeType` method is not very efficient. If you have to do this a lot, it will slow down your application. You could use a caching strategy to avoid this though. Or have a look at the [as3-commons-reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/index.html) project, it will take care of the caching for you.

Comment: If you're willing to be a bit looser than that, you can just look at the function's length parameter for the number of parameters it takes.

Comment: Your method name is `test` but the name in the XML is `start`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @merv Copy/pasting mistake. Fixing right now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Figured as much, but I didn't want to edited it myself, just in case I was reading it wrong.  Now you get the +1 ;)

Comment: Excellent. That's a great answer. I didnt know about haXe so I'll look that up. For the moment though I'll try the describeType. Thanks for your help.